# Python extension module with callbacks into Python

Tags: python, c++, callback, extension-modules

I am running into unpredictable behavior with my Python extension module that wraps around a C++ library that starts a new pthread and, after doing some work, generates callbacks back into the caller. I've greatly simplified this to a simplistic example which still demonstrates this problem. The following will sometimes generate a `Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate`, usually rather quickly. Sometimes it SIGSEGV on `tupledealoc`. Occasionally this deadlocks. I am at a loss why. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's my python test code

```py
import mymod
from time import sleep
from random import randrange

def my_cb1(s):
    print("Python cb %s" % (s));

for x in range(1,1000):
    num_cb = randrange(5) + 1
    print("Starting %d" % mymod.doit(my_cb1, "myid" + str(x), num_cb))

while True:
    sleep(1)
```

The extension module is:

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

static std::map<std::string, PyObject *> cb_map;
static std::mutex map_mtx;

struct fake_cb_info
{
  fake_cb_info() = delete;
  fake_cb_info(const unsigned long &num_cb, const std::string &id) :
    num_cb(num_cb), id(id)
  {
  }
  const unsigned long num_cb;
  const std::string id;
};
static std::deque<struct fake_cb_info> deq;
static std::mutex deq_mtx;

static bool is_worker_thread_running = false;
static std::thread worker_thread;

typedef std::function<void(const std::string &id, const std::string &s)> doit_cb_t;
static void internal_cb(const std::string &id, const std::string &s)
{
  std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(map_mtx);

  if (0 != cb_map.count(id))
  {
      PyGILState_STATE gstate;
      gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

      PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue("(s)", s.c_str());
      PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(cb_map.at(id), arglist);
      Py_DECREF(arglist);

      if (NULL == result)
      {
          if (NULL == PyErr_Occurred())
          {
            std::cerr << "Unknown error occurred in C callback" << std::endl;
          }
          else
          {
              PyErr_Print();
          }
      }
      else
      {
        Py_DECREF(result);
      }

      PyGILState_Release(gstate);
  }
  else
  {
    std::cerr << "Unknown callback id " << id << std::endl;
  }
}

void static worker()
{
  size_t x = 0;
  while(true)
  {
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(deq_mtx);
    if (deq.size() == 0)
    {
      usleep(1000);
      continue;
    }

    auto info = deq.front();
    deq.pop_front();
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<info.num_cb; i++)
    {
      internal_cb(info.id, std::to_string(x++));
    }
  }
}

PyObject * _wrap_doit(void *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    PyObject *py_retval;
    PyThreadState *py_thread_state = NULL;
    PyObject *cb;
    const char *id = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t id_len;
    std::string id_std;
    unsigned long num_callbacks;
    const char *keywords[] = {"cb_func", "id", "num_cb", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, (char *) "Os#k", (char **) keywords, &cb, &id, &id_len, &num_callbacks))
    {
        abort();
    }
    if (!PyCallable_Check(cb))
    {
        abort();
    }

    id_std = std::string(id, id_len);

    {
      std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(map_mtx);
      if (0 == cb_map.count(id_std))
      {
        Py_INCREF(cb);
        cb_map.insert(std::make_pair(id_std, cb));

        // N.B. The corresponding Py_DECREF for the callback function PyObject
        // is intentionally not here. It is in another extension module method
        // that is not listed here (just trying to keep this example as small
        // and lean as possible)
      }
      else
      {
        std::cerr << "Only one callback for ID!" << std::endl;
        abort();
      }
    }

    if (PyEval_ThreadsInitialized ())
    {
      std::cout << "Saving thread" << std::endl;
      py_thread_state = PyEval_SaveThread();
    }

    {
      // Stash away the info so that we will know how many callbacks to
      // generate and sleep a bit. This is to simulate a real external library
      // doing work which will, in turn, generate callbacks
      struct fake_cb_info info(num_callbacks, id_std);
      std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(deq_mtx);
      deq.push_back(info);

      if (!is_worker_thread_running)
      {
        std::cout << "@@@@ Creating a new thread\n";
        worker_thread = std::thread(&worker);
        pthread_setname_np(worker_thread.native_handle(), "worker_thread");
        worker_thread.detach();
        is_worker_thread_running = true;
      }

      usleep(10000);
    }

    if (py_thread_state)
    {
      std::cout << "Restoring thread" << std::endl;
      PyEval_RestoreThread(py_thread_state);
    }

    py_retval = Py_BuildValue((char *) "k", num_callbacks);
    return py_retval;
}

static PyMethodDef mymod_functions[] = {
    {
      (char *) "doit",
      (PyCFunction) _wrap_doit,
      METH_KEYWORDS | METH_VARARGS,
      "Generate requested number of multi-threaded callbacks.\n doit(callback_fn, id, num_callbacks)"
    },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "mymod",
    "pthread test module",
    -1,
    mymod_functions,
};

#define MOD_ERROR NULL
#define MOD_INIT(name) PyObject* PyInit_##name(void)
#define MOD_RETURN(val) val

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
#endif

#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#endif


MOD_INIT(mymod)
{
    PyObject *m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    if (m == NULL) {
        return MOD_ERROR;
    }
    return MOD_RETURN(m);
}
```

If you want to skip the `setup.py` step for compiling the extension module, here's a shell script I used to build it

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eux

obj='test_python_cmodule.o'
lib='mymod.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
if [ -f $obj ]; then
  rm $obj
fi
if [ -f $lib ]; then
  rm $lib
fi

g++ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I.  -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c test_python_cmodule.cpp -o $obj -std=c++17 -Wno-unused-variable -g -O0

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 $obj -lpthread -o $lib -lstdc++
```

Comment: An interesting observation - this test was done on Ubuntu 18.04 with the current latest Python3 which is 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.3. If I run this test using Python 3.8.5 (via PyEnv) then there is no problem. Moreover, if I run this test using Python 3.6.9 (via PyEnv), then I again see the problem. Does this mean that 3.6.9 has issues?

Answer (score 0):

The observation that the problem only happens with Python 3.6 but not newer versions led to the solution (posted on comp.lang.python) which is that in these older versions of Python, `PyEval_InitThreads()` must be called explicitly at least once in the main thread. In Python3.7 it is automatically called by Python, with the actual function deprecated in Python 3.9, slated for complete removal from public API in Python 3.11